# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'orderItems') and Return Not being created

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript and react, and I'm trying to create a page to return orders for an e-commerce website that I'm creating. I am trying to create this page in a similar way to which the orders are created. Also, I am trying to be able to create a return by pressing a make return button on a customers order history page. My issue is that the order returns are not being created, and currently, in my console in my order history page I'm getting a **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'orderItems')** error within the `const placeDevolucionHandler = () => {dispatch(createDevolucion({ ...order, devolucionItems: order.orderItems })); };` line of my code. I'm unsure why I am having this problem as I followed all the steps that I had done when creating my orders from my cart. I would really appreciate any help or guidance on how to fix this issue.
Thank you!

Note: devolucion is the name that I used in place of return.

OrderHistoryScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listOrderMine, detailsOrder } from '../actions/orderActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import {createDevolucion } from '../actions/devolucionActions';
import { DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/devolucionConstants';

export default function OrderHistoryScreen(props) {
  const orderId = props.match.params.id;
  const order = useSelector((state) => state.order);
  const devolucionCreate = useSelector((state) => state.devolucionCreate);
  const {success, devolucion } = devolucionCreate;

  const orderMineList = useSelector((state) => state.orderMineList);
  const { loading, error, orders } = orderMineList;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listOrderMine());
    dispatch(detailsOrder(orderId));
  }, [dispatch, orderId]);
  const placeDevolucionHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createDevolucion({ ...order, devolucionItems: order.orderItems }));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      props.history.push(`/devolucion/${devolucion._id}`);
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET });
    }
  }, [dispatch, devolucion, props.history, success]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Order History</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {orders.map((order) => (
              <tr key={order._id}>
               
                <td>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={placeDevolucionHandler}
                  className="small"
                
                >
                  Make a Return
                </button>
                </td>
             
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

PlaceOrderScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {createOrder,  } from '../actions/orderActions';
import CheckoutSteps from '../components/CheckoutSteps';
import { ORDER_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/orderConstants';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';

export default function PlaceOrderScreen(props) {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  if (!cart.paymentMethod) {
    props.history.push('/payment');
  }
  const orderCreate = useSelector((state) => state.orderCreate);
  const { loading, success, error, order } = orderCreate;
  

  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const placeOrderHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createOrder({ ...cart, orderItems: cart.cartItems }));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      props.history.push(`/order/${order._id}`);
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_RESET });
    }
  }, [dispatch, order, props.history, success]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row top">
        <div className="col-2">
          <div className="card card-body">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <h2>Order Summary</h2>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={placeOrderHandler}
                  className="primary block"
                  disabled={cart.cartItems.length === 0}
                >
                  Place Order
                </button>
              </li>
              {loading && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
              {error && <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

devolucionActions.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
  DEVOLUCION_CREATE_FAIL,
  DEVOLUCION_CREATE_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_FAIL,
  DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  DEVOLUCION_PAY_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_PAY_FAIL,
  DEVOLUCION_PAY_SUCCESS,
  DEVOLUCION_MINE_LIST_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_MINE_LIST_FAIL,
  DEVOLUCION_MINE_LIST_SUCCESS,
  DEVOLUCION_LIST_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_LIST_SUCCESS,
  DEVOLUCION_LIST_FAIL,
  DEVOLUCION_DELETE_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_DELETE_SUCCESS,
  DEVOLUCION_DELETE_FAIL,
  DEVOLUCION_SHIPPED_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_SHIPPED_SUCCESS,
  DEVOLUCION_SHIPPED_FAIL,
  DEVOLUCION_DELIVER_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_DELIVER_SUCCESS,
  DEVOLUCION_DELIVER_FAIL,
  DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_SUCCESS,

} from '../constants/devolucionConstants';



export const createDevolucion = (devolucion) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_REQUEST, payload: devolucion });
  try {
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    const { data } = await Axios.post('/api/devolucions', devolucion, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    });
    dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: data.devolucion });
    
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
export const detailsDevolucion = (devolucionId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: devolucionId });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/devolucions/${devolucionId}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };

  export const listDevolucion = ({ seller = '' }) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_LIST_REQUEST });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/devolucions?seller=${seller}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      console.log(data);
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_LIST_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };

  export const summaryDevolucion = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_REQUEST });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/devolucions/summary', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers';
import {
  devolucionCreateReducer,
  devolucionDeleteReducer,
  devolucionShipReducer,
  devolucionDeliverReducer,
  devolucionDetailsReducer,
  devolucionListReducer,
  devolucionMineListReducer,
  devolucionPayReducer,
  devolucionSummaryReducer,
} from './reducers/devolucionReducers';
import {
  orderCreateReducer,
  orderDeleteReducer,
  orderShipReducer,
  orderDeliverReducer,
  orderDetailsReducer,
  orderListReducer,
  orderMineListReducer,
  orderPayReducer,
  orderSummaryReducer,
} from './reducers/orderReducers';
import {
    productCategoryListReducer,
    productCreateReducer,
    productDeleteReducer,
    productDetailsReducer,
    productListReducer,
    productReviewCreateReducer,
    productUpdateReducer,
} from './reducers/productReducers';
import {
  userDeleteReducer,
  userDetailsReducer,
  userListReducer,
  userRegisterReducer,
  userSigninReducer,
  userUpdateProfileReducer,
  userUpdateReducer,
} from './reducers/userReducers';

const initialState = {
  userSignin: {
    userInfo: localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
      : null,
  },  
  cart: {
        cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
          ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
          : [],
        shippingAddress: localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress')
          ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress'))
          : {},
          paymentMethod: 'PayPal',
      },
};
const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer, 
  productCreate: productCreateReducer,
  productUpdate: productUpdateReducer,
  productDelete: productDeleteReducer,
  productReviewCreate: productReviewCreateReducer,
  productCategoryList: productCategoryListReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
  userSignin: userSigninReducer,
  userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
  userList: userListReducer,
  userDelete: userDeleteReducer,
  userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
  userUpdateProfile: userUpdateProfileReducer,
  userUpdate: userUpdateReducer,
  orderCreate: orderCreateReducer,
  orderDetails: orderDetailsReducer,
  orderPay: orderPayReducer,
  orderMineList: orderMineListReducer,
  orderList: orderListReducer,
  orderDelete: orderDeleteReducer,
  orderShip: orderShipReducer,
  orderDeliver: orderDeliverReducer,
  devolucionCreate: devolucionCreateReducer,
  devolucionDetails: devolucionDetailsReducer,
  devolucionPay: devolucionPayReducer,
  devolucionMineList: orderMineListReducer,
  devolucionSummary: devolucionSummaryReducer,
  devolucionList: devolucionListReducer,
  devolucionDelete: devolucionDeleteReducer,
  devolucionShip: devolucionShipReducer,
  devolucionDeliver: devolucionDeliverReducer,
  devolucionSummary: devolucionSummaryReducer,
  
  
});
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

Comment: There's way too much code here. Please create a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, error messages say which line of code produced the error so which of your 3 instances of `.orderItems` is it?

Comment: Is this a typo ~ `useSelector((state) => state.oder)`? Should that be `state.order`?

Comment: @Phil Yes, that was a typo. I just edited that. The issue is within ```const placeDevolucionHandler = () => {dispatch(createDevolucion({ ...order, devolucionItems: order.orderItems })); };```

Comment: The error seems pretty simple to debug. `order` comes from your store (`state.order`). It's a bit difficult to help you further without seeing how your redux store and reducers are defined.

Comment: @Phil I just added my store.js document. Is that helpful?

Comment: Your store doesn't have an `order` property so it shouldn't be surprising that it's `undefined`